# What is the status today of dye-transfer (a process-technology for printing)?

Tags: printing, digital-vs-film, technology-generations

What is today's status of the [dye-transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dye-transfer_process) process-technology for printing?

It is a technology that peaked in the 1980s, but due to rapid pace of innovation the printing industry it is now almost extinct.

I know there are some labs or specialists that still have committed to the technology. Is it because of large investment, or because of nostalgia?  Or are there any technical reasons to keep it alive (such as, maybe: superior long-term color stability, high gamut of some tonal ranges). Has there been any innovation in that area?

Comment: Possibly see [The Great Last Dye Transfer Blowout Print Sale](http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2013/04/cteins-great-last-blowout.html) from 2013 on TOP and [Ctein's 2011 webpage on dye transfer](http://ctein.com/dyetrans.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The status is that the materials have been discontinued and the process replaced by high end inkjet printing.

I believe there are some dye transfer digital techniques involving an inkjet printer and some special materials, the results are supposed to be great, but I can't offer any personal experience.